# "App not installed" after a new version of App is created. [IONIC 3]

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3

When a new version/update of an existing app is built, the app is not installed/updated over existing APK, whereas if the APK isn't installed previously on the device the updated APK is installed easily

All I did was changing the version from '1.0.0' to '1.0.1' in config.xml file
[image]
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Plese make sure , you remove existing plugins , platform , node_modules. And also please give result from terminal when you run - ```ionic cordova build android```

Comment: Uninstall old APK and reinstall this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to remove all existing platform, node_modules, plugins, www folders.
Use below command in the project root directory:

`rm -rf platforms/ node_modules/ plugins/ www/ .sourcemaps/ .tmp/`

`npm i`

`ionic cordova build android`